# Time-reversal in a simple current loop

Tags: electric-circuits, conductors, batteries, time-reversal-symmetry, electrochemistry

In classical physics, time and velocity change sign under time-reversal while position, acceleration and force do not. An accelerating particle going to the right becomes a decelerating particle going to the left.

In a simple current loop, imagining electrons with a constant drift velocity from $-$ pole towards $+$ pole after time-reversal we have the same electrons moving with the opposite drift velocity from $+$ pole towards $-$ pole. It seems like a new law in physics, but how would you explain that time-reversal in this situation does not violate any law of physics?

Answer (score 0):

Originally the battery is de-charging and chemical energy is transformed into
electromagnetic energy.
After time-reversal the battery is charging and electromagnetic energy is transformed into chemical energy.
Sorry for unintentionally answering my own question.
Maybe delete the question?

Comment: Answering your own question is an accepted use of this platform.